# Как использовать переменную класса String в имени создаваемого класса?

Tags: java, android

Есть переменная:

```
String name_class = "name1";
```

Есть класс:

```
MyClass
```

Хочу создать экземпляр класса используя переменную для имени:

```
MyClass name_class = new MyClass;
```

Но такая форма не прокатывает.

Как правильно написать?

И еще, как используя переменную name_class, найти класс с таким именем и обратиться к нему?
Например, как то так:

```
find(name1).getNum(int num);
```

Comment: Например, используйте `Map` для создания таких переменных. Там и поиск есть

Comment: C Map-ом понятно, это вторая часть вопроса, а как создавать классы используя имена из String? Например есть массив строк String[] и все созданные классы должны иметь имена из этого массива.

Comment: Если Вам нужен класс по его имени - рефлексия в помощь. Именование переменных - другая опера. Создание переменной переменных... Уверяю Вас, что есть другие более красивые способы решения Ваших задач, просто объясните, что Вы делаете?

Comment: Есть классы MyClass1, MyClass2...MyClassN, (наследники одного класса MyClass) которые содержит какие-то переменные. Из таких классов хочу создать ArrayList<MyClass> l_my_class. Выдергивать их из ArrayList хочу по названию класса. l_my_class.get(l_my_class.indexOf("MyClass1")).

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый ^_^

Answer (score 4):

Создать класс по имени, используя рефлексию, можно.

Если у вас есть класс, например:

```
public static class MyClass {

    public MyClass() {

    }

    public String justForTests() {
        return "test";
    }
}
```

Создать экземпляр можно так:

```
try {
    Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(MyClass.class.getName());
    Constructor<?> ctor = clazz.getConstructor();
    MyClass app = (MyClass)ctor.newInstance();

    System.out.println(app.justForTests());
}
catch (ClassNotFoundException | NoSuchMethodException | SecurityException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException | InvocationTargetException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

В вашем случае будет так:

```
String name_class = "полное_имя_класса";
Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(name_class);
```

Но нужно помнить, что `name_class` - полное имя класса с пакетом, то есть, если класс лежит в пакете `ru.tests`, то должно быть так в итоге:

```
try {
    String name_class = "ru.tests.MyClass";
    Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(name_class);
    MyClass app = (MyClass)ctor.newInstance();

    System.out.println(app.justForTests());
}
catch (ClassNotFoundException | NoSuchMethodException | SecurityException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException | InvocationTargetException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Еще не попробовал реализовать. Увидел слово "рефлексия", подумал, наверно эта задача решается более современно. Можно поподробнее?

Comment: @kaaa Подробнее про что ?

Answer (score 1):

> Есть классы MyClass1, MyClass2...MyClassN, (наследники одного класса
>   MyClass) которые содержит какие-то переменные. Из таких классов хочу
>   создать ArrayList l_my_class. Выдергивать их из ArrayList
>   хочу по названию класса.
>   l_my_class.get(l_my_class.indexOf("MyClass1")).

Сохранение:

```
 Map<Class<? extends MyClass>, ? extends MyClass> map = new HashMap<>();
 map.put(MyClass1.class, new MyClass1(...)); 
 ...
 map.put(MyClassN.class, new MyClassN(...));
```

Получение:

```
 MyClass obj = map.get(MyClass1.class);
```

Если вам именно хочется строку (хотя класс куда правильнее), то можно так

```
 Map<String, ? extends MyClass> map = new HashMap<>();
 map.put(MyClass1.class.getName(), new MyClass1(...)); 
 ...
 map.put(MyClassN.class.getName(), new MyClassN(...));

 MyClass obj = map.get(MyClass1.class.getName());
```

**P.S.** Не знаю вашу задачу, но есть большое подозрение, что можно решить ее без использования таких структур. Посмотрите паттерн фабрика/фабричный метод и ему подобные, либо вообще Dependency Injection.